# What's the Statistical test to use to compare the means of two correlated time series (i.e., t-test for time series)?

Tags: r, time-series, hypothesis-testing, t-test, autocorrelation

I hope everyone is doing well. I have a question about the statistical methods of comparing two time series. I got monthly data from 1/1/2019 – 1/10/19 (10 observations). I would like to compare it to another time series date from 1/1/2020 – 1/12/2020 ( 12 observations).
I’m interested in comparing the two time series and test the hypothesis that the means are equal or not (similar to a t-test). However, I don’t think doing a t-test is appropriate here because (1): the observations in each series are correlated.
What’s the appropriate statistical test in this case? How to conduct it in R.
Thank you very much for your help.
I included the data in the Excel file.

[image]

Comment: One's first thought should be to perform a paired t-test.  Do you have evidence, or make any assumptions, suggesting the sequence of *differences* would be serially correlated?  If not, you're good to go.

Comment: This might be a duplicate. Consider searching for a similar question among the existing ones.

Comment: Thanks. I already searched and found a question of comparing two series at the same time interval.  My data is at different time intervals.  Thanks.

Comment: How does the difference in time intervals matter for the comparison?

Comment: @whuber Thaks for your question.  If I understood your question correctly, I think it's important to account for the correlation between each point.

Comment: The paired test does exactly that.

Comment: The biggest issue is that by doing a paired t-test, the assumption will be violated. The observations are independent of one another.  In my case, the observations are dependent and correlated.  Thanks.